# How to get meaningful Laravel errors?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

With errors like this:

> ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)  Trying to get property of non-object
>   (View: /to/path/assign_template.blade.php)

How do I figure out line number where error is being produced?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 4, on the left side you can click back down through the stack trace. Usually in views, 3-4 calls down will be the actual error that occurred in your view file.

That error is caused by trying to access the property of something that isn't an object, usually I find this is when trying to access relations to a model. Something like `$model->relation->attribute`. `$model->relation` in that case is usually null.